# Problem with math in smarty!

Tags: smarty

I'm trying to plus and multiply three values in my template file but smarty is messing with me

```
{assign var="x" value="`$smarty.get.pageID * $perPage`"}
{$x + $smarty.section.co.index_next}
```

How can I do that?!

Comment: i found my answer i do it like this : 
{math equation="(( x * y ) + z )" x=$smarty.get.pageID y=$perPage z=$smarty.section.co.index_next}
it's working but when $smarty.get.pageID is empty it's give me error how can i slove that ?

Comment: Why isn't this being don on the server side?

Comment: @Martins: smarty IS server-side

Comment: @carpii sorry, I meant - why isn't this being done with php, in the controller(model), not in the view...

Answer (score 1):

sorry that was a silly question i solve it like this :

```
{if $smarty.get.pageID ne 1 } 
                {assign var="x" value=$smarty.get.pageID}

                {math equation="(( x * y ) + z )" x=$x y=$perPage z=$smarty.section.co.index_next}

            {else}

                {$smarty.section.co.index_next}

            {/if}
```